# Force call to "highest" overloaded function instead of base function

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, overloading

I have a base class and many other classes (all derivating from the base class) which all implement the same function with the same parameters. My problem is as follows :

```
class Entity
{
public:
    int getx();
    int gety();
};

class Enemy : public Entity
{
public:
    int getx();
    int gety();
};

class Player : public Entity
{
public:
    int getx();
    int gety();
};

// all of the implementations actually differ

int distance(Entity *e1, Entity *e2)
{
    return e2->getx() + e2->gety() - e1->getx() - e2->gety();
    // here, it is always Entity::getx and Entity::gety that are called
}
```

What I want is that if I call, say, `distance(e, p)` with `e` an `Enemy` and `p` a `Player`, the respective function overloads are called, and not Entity's implementation.

How would I achieve this, if it is actually possible ? I searched quite a bit on here, and the closest question I found was making use of templates in quite a different context, so it didn't really help me : [Template function overload for base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290678/template-function-overload-for-base-class)

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Say hello to [virtual functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is actually one of the basic concepts in *OOP*: **Virtual Functions**.

The idea is exactly as you described it:

> A virtual function is a function that's being replaced by subclasses implementation when accessed via a base class pointer.

The syntax is pretty straight forward, simply add the keyword `virtual` to your base class function declaration. It is good practice (although not a requirement) to also mark overriding functions (those of the subclasses) with the `override` keyword.

Here's a [reference of virtual functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual).

You can change your code to:

```
class Entity
{
public:
    virtual int getx();
    virtual int gety();
};

class Enemy : public Entity
{
public:
    int getx() override;
    int gety() override;
};

class Player : public Entity
{
public:
    int getx() override;
    int gety() override;
};

// all of the implementations actually differ

int distance(Entity *e1, Entity *e2)
{
    return e2->getx() + e2->gety() - e1->getx() - e2->gety();
    // Now, the proper getx & gety are being called
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Amit states in the comments you're looking for virtual functions. You can update your `Entity` class as follows:

```
class Entity
{
public:
    // Add a virtual destructor to allow deletion through base pointer to work correctly
    // (e.g., E* e = new Player(); delete e;)
    virtual ~Entity();

    virtual int getx() const = 0; // 'const' isn't related to your question but
    virtual int gety() const = 0; // good to have, '= 0' is optional but helpful if
                                  // the base class isn't providing an implementation
};
```

Assuming C++11, it's also good to use `override` in the derived classes.

```
class Enemy : public Entity
{
public:
    // 'const' only necessary if specified in the base class
    // 'virtual' is more documentation it would still be virtual if omitted
    // 'override' enforces that the signature matches a virtual function
    virtual int getx() const override;
    virtual int gety() const override;
};
```

Comment: He might still want a constructable base class. This code assumes an abstract base.

Comment: @JorenHeit It doesn't assume anything. It clearly states that `= 0` is available and _optional_, since the OP wasn't aware of virtual functions it's pretty safe to assume they aren't aware of `= 0` either (it was provided in code so that the OP could see exactly where it is used versus just commenting that it can be used).

Comment: Sorry, missed that comment.

Comment: Those two functions getx() and gety() are actually implemented in Entity. There are classes derivating from Entity that don't implement them, thus Entity's ones should be called. Would that still work with your implementation ?

EDIT : never mind, I actually read the doc, of course it works.

Comment: @Matrefeytontias If the base class provides an implementation and you don't want to have to do anything in the derived classes then do not use `= 0` in the base class. Furthermore, even if you use `= 0` you may still provide an implementation in the base class but derived classes will be forced to declare and implement the virtual function, even if all they do is call the base implementation (I'm guessing this is not what you're going for).